# get data from external URL with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an external URL that gets parameters and prints a result like this:
`{"result": "not_avail"}`

I'm trying to use jQuery to get the result like this:

```
$.get("http://www.thepage.html?id=2&name=david", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

But nothing happens, I'm not getting an alert and not getting any errors in firebug. How can I solve this?

Comment: Due to same domain policy you wont get a result, try looking into jsonp

Comment: If the return is JSON, please use `$.getJSON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

from [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Try to use relative path tou your script (on same domain)

Comment: so there is no way i can get this data ?

Comment: is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: I agree with @arthur :-), if you really need this then make a php proxy script on your domain.

Comment: thanks
i used this code and it is working :-)
$jsonurl = "http://www.mysite.com?id=1";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

Answer (score 0):

Arthur is correct, if you are running PHP you can try something like this also for corssdomain ajax

http://phpfour.com/blog/2008/03/cross-domain-ajax-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Try [getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29)

```
$.getJSON("http://yoururl",function(data){
    $("#selector").data("JSONP",data);
});
```

To return data in JSON format you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) in PHP.